# Show that there is a compact set $E$ such that $\mu(E^c) \lt \epsilon$ and $f|_{E}$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{C}$ is Lebesgue measurable. Then for $\epsilon \gt 0$, show that there is a compact set $E$ such that $\mu(E^c) \lt \epsilon$ and $f|_{E}$ is continuous .

This is a problem from Folland (Page-64, Q44). It is known as Lusin's Theorem. I am sure there are questions related to this in the site but I wanted to see if my try is correct or not.

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there is a continuous function $g_n$ which vanishes outside a bounded set such that $$\int_{[a,b]} |f-g_n| \lt \dfrac{1}{n}$$
Letting $n \to \infty$ we have $g_n \to f$ in $L^1$. Then there is a sub-sequence $g_{n_{k}}$ such that $g_{n_k} \to f, \mu-$a.e. By Egoroff's theorem there is a $F \subset [a,b]$ such that $\mu(F) \lt \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $g_{n_k} \to f$ uniformly in $F^c$. Now there is an open set $U$ such that $\mu(U) \lt \mu(F)+\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$ with $F \subset U$. Hence $U^{c} \subset F^{c}$ and $U^c$ is compact (being a closed subset of $[a,b]$). Moreover $g_{n_k} \to f$ uniformly on $U^c$. Being a uniform limit of continuous functions, $f$ is continuous on $U^c$. And $\mu(U) \lt \mu(F)+\dfrac{\epsilon}{2} \lt \epsilon.$

This seems alright to me. Is this correct? In measure theory, certain results which seem not to be true, turn out to be true.

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function $f$ is not necessary integrable. So you may consider $f_N=f\times 1\{|f|\le N\}$ s.t. $\mu\{|f|>N\}<\varepsilon/3$. $f_N$ is integrable, so using your arugments, there is a sequence of continuous functions converging uniformly to $f_N$ on $F^c$ with $\mu(F)<\varepsilon/3$. Then select a compact set $E\subset\{|f|\le N\}\cap F^c$ s.t. $f\mid_E=f_N\mid_E$ and $\mu(E^c)<\varepsilon$.